# What do iOS developers call the dots on the bottom of a page that indicate the number of open windows in an application?

Tags: ios, iphone

Repeat: What do iOS developers call the visual dots on the bottom of a page that indicate the number of open windows in an application?

[image: Screen capture of iPhone Safari app]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a [page control](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or as the iOS HIG calls it a [page indicator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW4).

Answer (score 5):

Page Control Dots

"You use the UIPageControl class to create and manage page controls. A page control is a succession of dots centered in the control. Each dot corresponds to a page in the application’s document (or other data-model entity), with the white dot indicating the currently viewed page."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: BoltClock is correct: The iOS Human Interface Guidelines as well as the documentation for UIPageControl refer to the control as a "Page Indicator."

Comment: Thanks for the help btw.I think I'll refer to them in combination; 'page indicator dots.'