# How to make a view appear first when the app loads up, out of 3 views - IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, alignment, center, pagecontrol

I'm working on an IOS app. It has 3 screens(views) that'l appear in a [dotted page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396014/what-do-ios-developers-call-the-dots-on-the-bottom-of-a-page-that-indicate-the-n) when the app loads up. What's happening is when the app finishes loading, it'l directly start displaying at screen 1. But i want it to start at screen 2 (center screen). How can i do this? A link towards working example will be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using PageViewController or different one?

Comment: it's **PiPUIViewController** .And it's working now, please see my reply to below answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `UIPageControl`, set the `currentPage = 1`. Your `UIControlEventValueChanged` responder will handle the page change.

```
UIPageControl *myPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
[myPageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged:) forState:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[myPageControl setCurrentPage:1];
```

Comment: Thank you Ian. I didn't use UIPageControl, rather i used like, initializing the **Container** and making the index as 1 there, instead as 0, also **returning 1** from **presentationIndexForPageViewController**. Thanks for the help, Now it's working as needed.